# How to extract or list participant custom data?

Tags: participants

My event has custom data extending participants. I can't find any way to report, search or sort on the custom data.

I have found the relevant tables for the options but the sql statement will be complex. I'd prefer to find a report already written. If I can't I could write my own stand alone page in php and query the database directly.

Edit: Here is the sql to show dinner preferences for each conference participant. I hard coded a couple of id numbers to save time.

SELECT civicrm_contact.display_name, civicrm_email.email, civicrm_phone.phone, civicrm_option_value.name
FROM civicrm_participant, civicrm_contact, civicrm_phone, civicrm_email, civicrm_value_rpc_2023_meal_24, civicrm_option_value
where civicrm_participant.event_id=5
and civicrm_participant.status_id=1
and civicrm_participant.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id
and civicrm_participant.contact_id = civicrm_phone.contact_id
and civicrm_value_rpc_2023_meal_24.entity_id=civicrm_participant.id
and civicrm_option_value.option_group_id = 124
and civicrm_value_rpc_2023_meal_24.meal_preference_44 = civicrm_option_value.value
and civicrm_email.contact_id = civicrm_participant.contact_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fields are Searchable then they should show up as expandable sections in the Event Participants List Report

If they are not showing there then suggest you go to your Custom Fields and confirm if you set them to be Searchable or not.

Comment: I am just learning the system and didn't see that setting. Thank you it works now. BTW the extended reports is throwing an error: Undefined index: email_on_hold_value in /home/noyb/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Utils/Report.php on line 500. How to fix?